# Java on android studio, why I cant see the Rectangle i drew in canvas?

Tags: java, android

Hi guys I recently started developing an android game, but i have encountered an issue with drawRectangle.

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(100,100,100,100), new Paint(Color.WHITE));
```

}

this Doesnt seem to work, but i have already drew on screen using another class with a draw method using the same logic but im curious why this doesnt work

private  Paint myPaint = new Paint();

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(100,100,100,100), myPaint);


}
```

this doesnt work either

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues in your implementation:-

- Paint object doesn't take color in constructor, it takes a flag.
  So you could have done something like `Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)` and then set the color as `p.setColor(Color.WHITE)`.
- The Rect object should be something like `new Rect(0,0,100,100)`.
  In your case [`new Rect(100,100,100,100)`] the rectangle will be drawn as a rectangle with 0 width,
  0 height and its upper left coordinate will be (100,100) and its
  bottom right coordinate will be (100,100).
- NEVER create objects in onDraw.

Answer (score 0):

Paint's constructor doesn't take a color.  It takes integer flags.  So you just made a really weird paint object with every flag set, but you didn't set the color.

See:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#Paint(int)

Comment: private  Paint myPaint = new Paint();

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawRect(new Rect(100,100,100,100), myPaint);
       
    }

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(testRect, myPaint);
```

}

Where
 private Rect testRect =  new Rect(0,0,100,100}

private  Paint myPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);